# Linq To object returns 0 values

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to get some data from to Lists using Linq. If I use join with equals using one field in each list it's ok and returns number of records as expected, but if I try use join on pair of fields it returns 0 records. Why?

```
List<Result> inner_join = 
    (from egais in rests_egais
    //join best in rests_best on egais.Product.AlcCode equals best.Product.AlcCode
    join best in rests_best 
    on new {key1 = egais.Shop, key2 = egais.Product.AlcCode} 
    equals new { key1 = best.Shop, key2 = best.Product.AlcCode }
    where egais.Quantity != best.Quantity
    select new Result
    {
       Shop = egais.Shop,
       AlcCode = egais.Product.AlcCode,
       FullName = egais.Product.FullName,
       Quantity_Egais = egais.Quantity,
       Quantity_Best = best.Quantity,
       Difference = best.Quantity - egais.Quantity
    }).ToList();
```

EDITED: These are classes to use:

```
public class Rest
{
    public Rest()
    {
        Product = new Product();
    }
    public string Shop { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    public string InformF1RegId { get; set; }
    public string InformF2RegId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Producer = new Producer();
    }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string AlcCode { get; set; }
    public double Capacity { get; set; }
    public string UnitType { get; set; }
    public double AlcVolume { get; set; }
    public int ProductVCode { get; set; }
    public Producer Producer { get; set; }
}
public class Producer
{
    public string ClientRegId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public int Country { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class Result
{
    public string Shop { get; set; }
    public string AlcCode { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public double Quantity_Egais { get; set; }
    public double Quantity_Best { get; set; }
    public double Difference { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use references as keys?

Comment: Hard to tell without sample data. What is `Shop` and what type is `AlcCode`?

Comment: What type is egais.Shop?

Comment: rests_egais and rests_best are both have type List<Rest>. Shop and AlcCode are strings

Comment: This is impossible to diagnose without example input, actually output, and desired output.  Best guess is that you don't have any items in the two lists that exactly match on both properties but not on `Quantity`.

Comment: if I use "join best in rests_best on egais.Product.AlcCode equals best.Product.AlcCode" it works ok, but when I want to use 2 fields to compare in join it doesn't work

Comment: Have you tired to do the same thing with only Shop as key?

Comment: @ИванИванов Imagine that you have ("AA", "BB") as an item in one list and ("AA", "CC") in another.  If you join on the first value you'll get a result, but if you join on both there will be no matches.  Joining means both should match, maybe you actually want to join if either matches instead?

Comment: I want to get something like SQL query: Select * from t1 join t2 on t1.a - t2.a and t1.b = t2.b where t1.c <> t2.c

Comment: OK that's what it should be doing, but again what is the actual data?  Are you sure you have items in the first that will match items in the second on both criteria.

Comment: My fault. I accedentaly added the odd symbol to a Shop field when I was creatint rests_best and that's why t1.shop wasn't equals to t2.shop. Thank you very much